# What is Sequence to Sequence Learning with Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Chat bot can be created with Sequence to Sequence Learning with Neural Networks, I have training chat-data but how to use it?

Comment: Your question is way too vague and broad. I'm quite certain you're referring to a specific paper by Google. As such, this is not a place to discuss it. There was a reddit thread about their methodology, though.

Comment: I am not referring to any paper, just want to know how can we use this model to create chat bot, if i have some chat data.

Comment: What it your current knowledge? You know how to use neural networks? Including recurrent ones? Time-series prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sequence to Sequence Learning using Neural networks* is a way to use Neural Networks to translate sequences. The general goal is you have a source sequence(say a sentence in English), a target sequence(it's translation in French) and the task is to generate target sequence looking at source sequence.

Challenges for traditional Feed Forward Neural Networks are varying source and target lengths. [In this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3215), they use a Recurrent neural Network(RNN) to encode the source sequence i.e, the RNN reads the individual elements in source sequence one-by-one. Once it finishes, the encoder would be having a fair idea of what the source sequence is.

You use the last state of the encoder and provide this additional information to Decoder(which is basically a language model) to generate the target sequence element by element.

In your case, you can use it to generate responses. Say you have chat messages between two users. Now chat message of user 1 would be source sequence and the corresponding reply from user 2 would be target sequence. The training is done as said in the paper. The model after training would be trying to mimick user 2 response.